# Importing shapefile in Google Earth, CRS problem

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, google-earth, utm

I have a line shapefile in QGIS, my project and layers CRS is MGI 1901 Balkans zone 7.

When I import it in Google Earth it is misplaced a little. I understand that Google Earth is in UTM and mine is in TM, so how can I solve this and have it placed correctly?

---

Here are screenshots of data properties and export dialogue

[image: scrshot1]

[image: scrshot2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your data to either UTM or WGS 84 within QGIS vector layer export, and import that as `ESRI shape` in Google Earth.

[image]

Comment: I've tried that and it didnt work. Shapefile was largery misplaced. A tried to make a new project. with wgs84 crs and i drew a shapefile also in wgs84, when I imported it in google earth, gave me these warnings: "Some features were not imported due to invalid or out of range coordinates."

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of your data and of the export dialogue?

Comment: There are lots of CRSs that use WGS84. I use EPSG:3857 when importing a Google Earth KML to Qgis.

Comment: @HDunn I've posted screenshot as answers below

Comment: @СтеванСтојиљковић There is some CRS issue with your layers. Your map is set to 4326 (bottom right), but your units show values of MGI 1901 Balkans zone 7 which are inconsistent with the geographic CRS, and that is probably why you get the out of range error. Change your project CRS to MGI 1901 Balkans zone 7, Make sure the layers are positioned correctly too. If not, redefine their source CRS, and only then export as WGS84 to view in Google Earth.

Comment: @HDunn thanks! it worked! i'm sure i've tried this but something didnt work it out. Now is good. Thank you, again!